# How to use the following command from R: echo "${pipestatus[1]}"?

Tags: r, zsh, system2

I need to check the exit status of a piped command from R on Debian, like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another), but cannot make run `echo "${pipestatus[1]}"` successfully from R using `system2`/`system` function. The command works properly when I use command line.

The command I am trying to use in R can look like this (the shell I use is zsh):

```
system2("false", args = "|true;echo '${pipestatus[1]}'")
```

After some testing I can see that the exit status checking command cannot be quoted properly but I cannot figure out the correct way to do so.

Am I right that quoting this command properly is the issue? How to run this (`echo "${pipestatus[1]}"`) command from R? Are there any alternatives to using the command in question to check exit status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use zsh features here, since `system2` doesn’t invoke a shell.

Instead, you’ll either need to use a raw `system` call or, better, explicitly invoke the shell in `system2`. You’ll also need to use double quotes instead of single quotes around `${pipestatus[1]}` to allow expansion — otherwise zsh will interpret it as a literal string.

```r
system2('zsh', c('-c', shQuote('false|true; echo "${pipestatus[1]}"')))
```